# jQuery / JS setting global variables but stuck passing to AJAX custom function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to set some global vars but a little stuck on how to then fire the custom function which does a AJAX request with the data, I collect email in one function and other events and also firstname and lastname but I'm now stuck.

I've not called fireCheckoutAC anywhere as this is what I'm stuck with. I'm new to jQuery and JS but think I've got as far as I can.

```
// set global variables
var checkoutEmail = "";
var checkoutFirstName = "";
var checkoutLastName = "";

$(document).ready(function() {

    function fireCheckoutAC(checkoutEmail, checkoutFirstName, checkoutLastName) {
        $.ceAjax('request', fn_url('ac.email'), {
            method: 'post',
            data: {
                'email': checkoutEmail,
                'firstname': checkoutFirstName,
                'lastname': checkoutLastName
            },
            caching: true
        });
    }
    // function to check email field, validate and save to ac for this customer session
    function checkIt(field) {
        field = $(field);
        var email = field.val();
        var emailError = "<p>The email address in the <b>E-mail</b> field is invalid.</p>";
        var emailInputId = field.attr('id');
        if ($("." + emailInputId + "_error_message").length > 0) {
            $("." + emailInputId + "_error_message").remove();
        }
        //console.log($(emailInputId+"_error_message"));
        if (validEmail(email)) {
            //alert('valid email');
            checkoutEmail = email;
            field.removeClass('cm-failed-field');
            field.prev().removeClass('cm-failed-label');
            field.next("span").remove();
        } else {
            field.addClass('cm-failed-field');
            field.prev().addClass('cm-failed-label');
            field.after("<span class='" + emailInputId + "_error_message help-inline' ><p>" + emailError + "</p></span>");
        }
    }

    // lets check if the email input was already populated, such as browser auto fill etc.. if so use that and save
    var field = $('#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-email input')[0];
    if ($(field).length > 0) {
        if (field.value) {
            checkIt(field);
        }
    }

    // check email thats inputted and save to ac session for this customer, or if email changed to update
    $('#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-email input').blur(function() {
        checkIt(this);
    });

    // if first name entered lets grab it and add to the ac session for the customer
    var firstname_sel = '#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-first-name input';
    var lastname_sel = '#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-last-name input';

    $(firstname_sel+','+lastname_sel).blur(function() {
        checkoutFirstName = $(firstname_sel).val();
        checkoutLastName = $(lastname_sel).val();
    });

    // lets grab the first name and last name if already in input
    var firstname_sel_pre = $('#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-first-name input')[0];
    var lastname_sel_pre = $('#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-last-name input')[0];
    if ($(firstname_sel_pre).length > 0 || $(lastname_sel_pre).length > 0) {
        if (firstname_sel_pre.value || lastname_sel_pre.value) {
            checkoutFirstName = $(firstname_sel_pre).val();
            checkoutLastName = $(firstname_sel_pre).val();
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle.net

Comment: Its ok i managed to work it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to work it out, here is the solution for anyone else wanting to know... just had to call the ajax function which handled the global vars

```
/* grab completed email when enetred into checkout and add to abandoned cart 

for that session */
function validEmail(v) {
    var r = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
    return (v.match(r) == null) ? false : true;
}

// set global variables
var checkoutEmail = "";
var checkoutFirstName = "";
var checkoutLastName = "";

$(document).ready(function() {

    function fireCheckoutAC() {
        $.ceAjax('request', fn_url('ac.email'), {
            method: 'post',
            data: {
                'email': checkoutEmail,
                'firstname': checkoutFirstName,
                'lastname': checkoutLastName
            },
            caching: true
        });
    }
    // function to check email field, validate and save to ac for this customer session
    function checkIt(field) {
        field = $(field);
        var email = field.val();
        var emailError = "<p>The email address in the <b>E-mail</b> field is invalid.</p>";
        var emailInputId = field.attr('id');
        if ($("." + emailInputId + "_error_message").length > 0) {
            $("." + emailInputId + "_error_message").remove();
        }
        //console.log($(emailInputId+"_error_message"));
        if (validEmail(email)) {
            //alert('valid email');
            checkoutEmail = email;
            fireCheckoutAC();
            field.removeClass('cm-failed-field');
            field.prev().removeClass('cm-failed-label');
            field.next("span").remove();
        } else {
            field.addClass('cm-failed-field');
            field.prev().addClass('cm-failed-label');
            field.after("<span class='" + emailInputId + "_error_message help-inline' ><p>" + emailError + "</p></span>");
        }
    }

    // lets check if the email input was already populated, such as browser auto fill etc.. if so use that and save
    var field = $('#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-email input')[0];
    if ($(field).length > 0) {
        if (field.value) {
            checkIt(field);
        }
    }

    // check email thats inputted and save to ac session for this customer, or if email changed to update
    $('#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-email input').blur(function() {
        checkIt(this);
    });

    // if first name entered lets grab it and add to the ac session for the customer
    var firstname_sel = '#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-first-name input';
    var lastname_sel = '#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-last-name input';

    $(firstname_sel+','+lastname_sel).blur(function() {
        checkoutFirstName = $(firstname_sel).val();
        checkoutLastName = $(lastname_sel).val();
        fireCheckoutAC();
    });

    // lets grab the first name and last name if already in input
    var firstname_sel_pre = $('#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-first-name input')[0];
    var lastname_sel_pre = $('#onestepcheckout .ty-billing-last-name input')[0];
    if ($(firstname_sel_pre).length > 0 || $(lastname_sel_pre).length > 0) {
        if (firstname_sel_pre.value || lastname_sel_pre.value) {
            checkoutFirstName = $(firstname_sel_pre).val();
            checkoutLastName = $(firstname_sel_pre).val();
            fireCheckoutAC();
        }
    }

});
```